# Launching "sudo dpkg --configure -a" restarts the pc and does not solve anything

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, dpkg

running a OpenCV-based code on Ubuntu, I incurred in the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. 
Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. 
If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then 
re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/opennao/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 275
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

So I tried to install this libgtk2.0-dev by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

but it returns the following:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."
```

And this is what I did. But then, during the processing of the command request, the pc restarts on its own and the problem comes again when I run my code.

For the sake of clarification, I think it's worth saying that two weeks ago an update on Ubuntu corrupted my grub to choose the OS to run (there are Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 on my pc), so I restored it through minimal-bash line editing.

Now, when I run "sudo dpkg --configure -a" I see that the last printed lines before restarting refer to some information about disk images or kernels that I rembember to have handled to fix the grub. I don't know if this can be a suggestion to understand the problem.
Thank you all for your support, ask me if you need further details.